# Draw Rectangle Over ImageView for highlight that can be zoom in-out in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have been refer this example from SO below are they.

1.[Draw Line Over ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831642/how-to-draw-lines-over-imageview-on-android)

2.[Draw Picture Over ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956774/android-draw-picture-over-imageview)

3.I have use this ImageView Class for my image to become zoom in-out [Image Pinch zoom code google](http://code.google.com/p/scale-imageview-android/source/browse/src/com/matabii/dev/scaleimageview/ScaleImageView.java).

**Now what i am try to do is :**

I want to  make zoom in by pinching the screen and other point is that when i do single tap a rectangle should be drawn over image view and i also want this rectangle should get zoom in & out with imageView's Zoom in and Zoom Out and i want to use it through `ScaleImageView`  class.

Output of this should look like below image.

[image: you can see when i make single tap over ImageViewit will draw rectangle like showing in image]

And i also known that ,this can be done by Using `Relative Layout` or may be by using `SurfaceView`in android but i am new for use Surface view and i also worry about if i use Another View over imageView to draw then do this both view work for zoom in and out . If i use SurfaceView over ImageView then do Image Can be able to zoom in and out .

By using this pinch zoom in-out example from here.[example that i use pinch zoom](http://code.google.com/p/scale-imageview-android/).

Now i draw Rectangle on Single Touch by below code in that example.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.v("Log_tag", "Draw Image View");
        //Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rect_image);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 10, 10, null);
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        /*if(bitmap!=null){
            if (x1 > 0 || x2 > 0 || y1 > 0 || y2 > 0){
                  Log.v("Log_tag", "ImageBitmap is draw");
                //Canvas mCanvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
                //mCanvas.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, mPaint);
                //  canvas.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom);
                   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                   paint.setColor(0xFF000000
                      + ((int)(PRESET_PRESSURE * pressure) <<16)
                      + ((int)(PRESET_PRESSURE * pressure) << 8)
                      + (int)(PRESET_PRESSURE * pressure));
                   //mCanvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, (PRESET_SIZE * size), paint);
            }

        }*/
        //canvas.save();
        //canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
       // canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mBitmapDrawable.draw(canvas);
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        Log.v("Log_tag", "Redraw with this point");
        canvas.drawRect(rect_x1-30,rect_y1-30, rect_x1+30, rect_y1+30, myPaint);
        mCanvasMatrix=canvas.getMatrix();
        mImageCanvas=canvas;

        canvas.setMatrix(mCanvasMatrix);
        //canvas.restore();

    }
```

**UPDATE**

Below is my class used for ImageView pinch zoom.

```
public class ImageViewScale extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.save();
        //canvas.scale(mScale, mScale);
        mCanvasMatrix=canvas.getMatrix();
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        if(mCanvasMatrix!=null){
            if(orignalRect!=null)
                mCanvasMatrix.mapRect(orignalRect);
        }
        if(orignalRect!=null){
            canvas.drawRect(orignalRect,myPaint);
        }
        //canvas.drawRect(rect_x1-30,rect_y1-30, rect_x1+30, rect_y1+30, myPaint);
        int canavs_width=canvas.getWidth();
        int canavs_height=canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.setMatrix(mCanvasMatrix);
        //canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);
        if(mDrawable!=null){
            //mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            Log.v("Log_tag", "draw with Canvas is done  W:"+ canavs_width+"H:"+ canavs_height);
        }
        //canvas.restore();
    }

    private float MAX_SCALE = 2f;
    private int DOUBLE_TAP_SECOND = 400;

    private float CANVAS_MAX_SCALE=2f;

    float rect_x1=50;
    float rect_y1=150;

    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private Matrix mCanvasMatrix;

    private final float[] mCanvasMatrixValues=new float[9];
    private final float[] mMatrixValues = new float[9];
    RectF orignalRect;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    // display width height.
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    private int mIntrinsicWidth;
    private int mIntrinsicHeight;

    private int mCanvasWidth;
    private int mCanvasHeight;


    private float mScale;
    private float mMinScale;

    private float mCanvasMinScale;

    // double tap for determining
    private long mLastTime = 0;
    private boolean isDoubleTap;
    private int mDoubleTapX;
    private int mDoubleTapY;

    private float mPrevDistance;
    private boolean isScaling;

    private int mPrevMoveX;
    private int mPrevMoveY;

    String TAG = "ScaleImageView";

    public ImageViewScale(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        initialize();
    }

    public ImageViewScale(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        this.initialize();

    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        this.mMatrix = new Matrix();
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        mDrawable=d;
        if (d != null) {
            mIntrinsicWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mIntrinsicHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.v("Log_tag", "Size are here "+ l + t + r+ b);
        mWidth = r - l;
        mHeight = b - t;

        mMatrix.reset();
        mScale = (float) r / (float) mIntrinsicWidth;
        int paddingHeight = 0;
        int paddingWidth = 0;
        // scaling vertical
        if (mScale * mIntrinsicHeight > mHeight) {
            mScale = (float) mHeight / (float) mIntrinsicHeight;
            mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
            paddingWidth = (r - mWidth) / 2;
            paddingHeight = 0;
            // scaling horizontal
        } else {
            mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
            paddingHeight = (b - mHeight) / 2;
            paddingWidth = 0;
        }
        mMatrix.postTranslate(paddingWidth, paddingHeight);

        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        mMinScale = mScale;
        zoomTo(mScale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
        cutting();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    protected float getValue(Matrix matrix, int whichValue) {
        matrix.getValues(mMatrixValues);
        return mMatrixValues[whichValue];
    }
    //New Added
    protected float getCanvasValue(Matrix matrix,int whichvalues){
        mCanvasMatrix.getValues(mCanvasMatrixValues);
        return mCanvasMatrixValues[whichvalues];
    }

    protected float getScale() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X);
    }

    //New added  Method
    protected float getCanvasScale(){
        return getCanvasValue(mCanvasMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X);
    }

    protected float getTranslateX() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X);
    }

    //New added Method
    protected float getCanvasTranslateX(){
        return getCanvasValue(mCanvasMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X);
    }


    protected float getTranslateY() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y);
    }

    //New Added Method
    protected float getCanvasTranslateY(){
        return getCanvasValue(mCanvasMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y);
    }

    protected void maxZoomTo(int x, int y) {
        if (mMinScale != getScale() && (getScale() - mMinScale) > 0.1f) {
            // threshold 0.1f
            float scale = mMinScale / getScale();
            zoomTo(scale, x, y);
        } else {
            float scale = MAX_SCALE / getScale();
            zoomTo(scale, x, y);
        }
    }




    protected void zoomTo(float scale, int x, int y) {
        if (getScale() * scale < mMinScale) {
            return;
        }
        if (scale >= 1 && getScale() * scale > MAX_SCALE) {
            return;
        }
        mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        // move to center
        mMatrix.postTranslate(-(mWidth * scale - mWidth) / 2,
                -(mHeight * scale - mHeight) / 2);

        // move x and y distance
        mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x - (mWidth / 2)) * scale, 0);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y - (mHeight / 2)) * scale);
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }


    protected void zoomToCanvas(float scale,int x,int y){
        if(getCanvasScale()* scale<mCanvasMinScale){
            return;
        }

        if(scale>=1 && getCanvasScale()*scale> CANVAS_MAX_SCALE){
            return;
        }
        mCanvasMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);



    }

    public void cutting() {
        int width = (int) (mIntrinsicWidth * getScale());
        int height = (int) (mIntrinsicHeight * getScale());
        if (getTranslateX() < -(width - mWidth)) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-(getTranslateX() + width - mWidth), 0);
        }
        if (getTranslateX() > 0) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-getTranslateX(), 0);
        }
        if (getTranslateY() < -(height - mHeight)) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(getTranslateY() + height - mHeight));
        }
        if (getTranslateY() > 0) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -getTranslateY());
        }
        if (width < mWidth) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate((mWidth - width) / 2, 0);
        }
        if (height < mHeight) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, (mHeight - height) / 2);
        }
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }

    private float distance(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1) {
        float x = x0 - x1;
        float y = y0 - y1;
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private float dispDistance() {
        return FloatMath.sqrt(mWidth * mWidth + mHeight * mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
            if (touchCount >= 2) {
                float distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                        event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                mPrevDistance = distance;
                isScaling = true;
            } else {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() <= mLastTime + DOUBLE_TAP_SECOND) {
                    if (30 > Math.abs(mPrevMoveX - event.getX())
                            + Math.abs(mPrevMoveY - event.getY())) {
                        isDoubleTap = true;
                        mDoubleTapX = (int) event.getX();
                        mDoubleTapY = (int) event.getY();
                    }
                }
                mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
                float dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                        event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                float scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance();
                mPrevDistance = dist;
                scale += 1;
                scale = scale * scale;
                zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
                cutting();
            } else if (!isScaling) {
                int distanceX = mPrevMoveX - (int) event.getX();
                int distanceY = mPrevMoveY - (int) event.getY();
                mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
                mMatrix.postTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                cutting();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP:
            if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1) {
                isScaling = false;
                if (isDoubleTap) {
                    if (30 > Math.abs(mDoubleTapX - event.getX())
                            + Math.abs(mDoubleTapY - event.getY())) {
                        maxZoomTo(mDoubleTapX, mDoubleTapY);
                        cutting();
                    }
                }
            }
            isDoubleTap = false;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int count_touch=event.getPointerCount();
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float point_x=event.getX();
            float point_y=event.getY();
            rect_x1=point_x;
            rect_y1=point_y;
            if(count_touch==1){
                orignalRect=new RectF(rect_x1-30, rect_y1-30, rect_x1+30,  rect_y1+30);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very obvious what you want done. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Richard till now i have ImageView that can able to pinch zoom in-out and now i have `@Override` onDraw Method of that ImageView to draw rectangle on User Touch ,it draw one rectangle over imageview but my problem is ImageView is able to  pinch zoom but a Rectangle is not work will it.So i want to apply same pinch zoom in-out that rectangle.

Comment: @Richard now may i think you got what i try to do?

Comment: "is not work will it"? Why not just apply the same transformation to the rectangle?

Comment: Yes .It is not working only Image is zoom in-out because when we draw rectangle over Image it will draw in canvas and most of pinch zoom working with `Matrix` zoom.

Comment: i also see this http://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/touchexample/TouchExampleView.java example for pinch zoom that may apply to canvas but it is not able to my desire out put.and it is not exact pinch zooom

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean that you want the rectangle to shrink when the user pinches and grow when the user slides the touchpoints apart? And that the rectangle should be contained inside the area between the finger tips? And that the rectangle sides behave like they follow the finger tips?

Comment: actually i just want to be my rectangle to shrink and grow according to ImageView 's Zoom in and out.and once we make single tap on image it will draw Rectangle and it have same zoom in-out like i have now with Image Pinch zoom.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to checkout [Matrix.mapRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapRect%28android.graphics.RectF%29). Use this method to transform the rectangle by the same amount as the image in the imageview.

```
boolean onTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
    ....
    // this rect dimensions should be initial values and should be a member.
    mOriginalRect = new RectF(rect_x1-30, rect_y1-30, rect_x1+30, rect_y1+30); 
    .....
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ....
    mCanvasMatrix = canvas.getMatrix();  ///matrix should have scale values..
    mCanvasMatrix.mapRect(tempRect, mOriginalRect); // mOriginalRect is src 
    canvas.drawRect(tempRect, myPaint);   // draw tempRect..
    ....
}
```

Comment: i am not get how i can apply `Matrix.mapRect` to ImagesView's Canvas .Sorry to ask this because i am new for working with Canvas and Image zooming.and i am using this method to draw `canvas.drawRect(rect_x1-30,rect_y1-30, rect_x1+30, rect_y1+30, myPaint);` rectangle with single Touch over `ImageView`.

Comment: when i have use `Matrix` that used for ImageView zoom in-out it work for only top left portion of my ImageView and it's rectangle is not draw exact at my touch point. and when i use  `mCanvasMatrix` then it will not make any zoom  in-out for rectangle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11254/discussion-between-userseven7s-and-herry)

Comment: i see your updated answer ,but what is `tempRect` ,i means it must be `RectF` ,but what is contain .

Comment: It is used to hold the transformed values of the `mOriginalRect`. Yesterday I realized we should not modify the `mOrignalRect` values.

Comment: Let just initialize Our `mOriginalRect` once and we draw rect over ImageView ,But still problem is we are not getting that rect zoom in-out same as `ImageView`.

Comment: do you known any example that use Pinch zoom for Android Canvas. I have found example from developer site but it is not exact pinch zoom.

Comment: That means the scale values are not in that canvas matrix. You should perform scaling on one canvas and then take the matrix from that canvas for doing the mapping... Check the matrix values by logging them... see if the scaled values are present in it...

Comment: I thought you were able to pinch zoom.. and your only problem was drawing the scaled rect over the zoomed image..

Comment: i try your last onDraw Method which make my rect too much small and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to extend ImageView, in the views onDraw(Canvas) you would draw the rectangle.

Extend ImageView once in order to make in pinch-to-zoom (which should use the Matrix in the image view to implement the pinch zoom)

Extend it again to take a rectangle, transform it using the image matrix and draw it after the super.draw() call.

Comment: i Have already Class with ImageView extends and i also apply Matrix after super.draw()  call but it is not exact work to make rectangle zoom in and out.You can see my `ImageViewScale` for what i try.

Comment: @HaMMedREd can you explain your answer i really not getting it?

Comment: What questions do you have. 

The rectangle you are trying to outline is made up of 4 points.

If you store the rectangle as RectF, and define the units as being in pixels in it (e.g. 30x30 rectangle at x=10,y=40) you then pass it through getImageMatrix().mapRect(definedRect, translatedRect) and then you take the translatedRect and just draw it using Canvas.drawRect(translatedRect, paint) and it should draw it in the correct location given the images transformation matrix.

Comment: I got my src/dest rect translation messed up, the parent you awarded explains it better than I have

Answer (score 1):

@ Herry - I have done a small POC on this type of issue and found that we have to exactly transform the canvas as we are transforming the imageview.

Example :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
Resources res = this.getResources();
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.circlered);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(1f, 1f);
canvas.restore();
canvas.save();
canvas.concat(mMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 100, 150, null);
}
```

Do try this ! and let me know.

Comment: You mean i have to write this code in onDraw method of my ImageView  class .that i use for pinch zoom.

Comment: You dont want to move the rectangle when you zoom in and out ?

Comment: yes once user make choice then it should stay on image and it just like flatter of two view .

Comment: yes ,i don't want to make move of ract when we are applying zoom in and  out.

Comment: can you able to draw rect on all area of image on single touch?

Comment: In my example i'm drawing a bitmap over a imageview on my desired location.

Answer (score 0):

### Draw Ractangle imageview

```
   public class RactangleImageView extends ImageView {
      private static final int strockwidth = 6;
      private Paint paintBorder;
      private Bitmap bitmap;
      private int strokeWidthPx;
      private RectF rectF;
      private RadialGradient radialGradient;
       public RactangleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
      }
     private void init() {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageicon);
        strokeWidthPx = (int) (strockwidth * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        int halfStrokeWidthPx = strokeWidthPx / 2;
        paintBorder = new Paint();
        paintBorder.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        int totalWidth = bitmap.getWidth() + strokeWidthPx * 2;
        int totalHeight = bitmap.getHeight() + strokeWidthPx * 2;
        radialGradient = new RadialGradient(totalWidth /2, totalHeight /2, totalWidth /2, new int[]    {Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN}, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        paintBorder.setShader(radialGradient);
        setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight,        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
          rectF = new RectF(halfStrokeWidthPx, halfStrokeWidthPx, totalWidth - halfStrokeWidthPx, totalHeight - halfStrokeWidthPx);
      }   
      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, 40, 40, paintBorder);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,strokeWidthPx, strokeWidthPx, null);
      }
    }
```