# Zoom in and zoom out in android image view having another image drawn with canvas over it

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

I have a image over which i have drawn an bitmap using canvas.
i have implemented zoom in and zoom out functionality on imageview, but the canvas which i have drawn doesn't move when there is a zooming effect on imageview.

i have to achieve a Google map type of view in which a marker stays there as we zoom in and zoom out the map (as this is a map functionality but i want to achieve it in imageview).

i have followed this link :
[Draw Rectangle Over ImageView for highlight that can be zoom in-out in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482229/draw-rectangle-over-imageview-for-highlight-that-can-be-zoom-in-out-in-android)
but didn't achieve the exact functionality what i want.

Comment: Try it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207955/how-to-zoom-an-image-on-absolutelayout-in-android/10209085#10209085

Comment: In the code how will i provide the 2 images which one over other ?